# JVM args in Websphere Application Server

Tags: jvm, websphere, args

I need to see all the JVM args that go to my websphere app server. Is it logged somewhere. Note: I dont wish to change any JVM args but just see what JVM args were used by the server to startup.

Like in Weblogic we have Server.out which has all the JVM startup parameters, so what would be for Websphere.

Answer (score 10):

You can view the JVM args via Administration Console. The path is:

> Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name

Then, under Server Infrastructure  click

> Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual
>   machine

The JVM entries can also be found in server.xml as tag

> jvmEntries

The path of server.xml is:

> C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile_name\config\cells\cell_name\nodes\node_name\servers\server_name\server.xml

Comment: @shifahim Just to clarify it a bit - in the `Java virtual machine` page of the admin console you can see entries in 2 places - in `Generic JVM arguments` and via link `Custom properties`. They might be defined in either place, so you will need to check both.

Comment: I ran into deadlock issue where I added one JVM arg and restarted server and server could not restart. So now there is no way for me to change JVM arguments from admin console. In such cases its really useful to know the location of those config files. The path to server.xml saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

The full JVM arguments are not logged by default. You can deduce them by looking at the Java virtual machine settings in the admin console. Some other ideas:

1. You can create a server script with `bin/startServer.bat -script server.bat`, which will show the full command-line used to start the process.
2. If you add the `-Xdump:java:events=vmstart` generic JVM argument, then a javacore will be created every time the server starts, and the javacore will contain a 1CICMDLINE with the full command-line for the server process (which will include the -Xdump option).

Comment: @shifahim You can also generate that javacore dump manually using `AdminControl.invoke(jvm, 'dumpThreads')`, if you don't need it on every restart, but by request.

Answer (score 0):

I research Websphere,
Please step by step check for you:

1. Web Console

Application servers > server1TPSrv01 > server1TPSrv01
It is recommended that you switch to High Performance Extensible Logging (HPEL) if you have no existing procedures that prevent you from taking advantage of it.

(Advised for most installations)
Use this page to select a system log to configure, or to specify a log detail level for components and groups of components. Use log levels to control which events are processed by Java logging.

General Properties

Diagnostic Trace

```
***JVM Logs***
```

Process Logs

IBM Service Logs

Change log detail levels

NCSA access and HTTP error logging

1.1 Click `JVM Log`

General Properties

System.out

Information required File Name:

```
> ${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/SystemOut.log
```

System.err

Information required File Name:

```
${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/SystemErr.log
```

2. Edit JVM parameter in server file

> wasadm@uat-tpx10 />vi
> *> /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/server1Cell01/nodes/server1TPNode05/servers/server1TPSrv05/server.xml*

Thanks and regards

Ngoc D.Tan